# Python element-tree SyntaxError: can't assign to literal.

Tags: python, xml, csv, elementtree

I getting the `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal` when trying to parse an XML and export tags to a csv .. the error is coming from the following string: `'Test Script (Steps) – Step'` .. here is a snip-it of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys, getopt
import csv

tree = ET.parse(inputfile)
root = tree.getroot()

# open a file for writing

testscript_data = open(outputfile, 'w')

# create the csv writer object

csvwriter = csv.writer(testscript_data)
testscript_head = []

count = 0
for member in root.findall('ns2:testscript'):
    testscript = []
    address_list = []
    if count == 0:
        'Test Script (Steps) – Step' = member.find('ns9:description').tag
        testscript_head.append('ns9:description')
```

I want a heading of the csv to be `Test Script (Steps) – Step` including the spaces... I have tried to turn it into a string as shown above, but idk if that is going to work.

any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: `'Test Script (Steps) – Step'` is a literal, you can't assign to it. What did you want `'Test Script (Steps) – Step' = member.find('ns9:description').tag` to do?

Comment: Perhaps `testscript_data.write('Test Script (Steps) – Step\n')` to make it a header for the csv? Notice that will will make it no longer a pure csv because the header isn't following the same rules as the other columns.